# Display bounty scores in user profile answers list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, profile-page, bounties

It would certainly take a while for me to look through my 300+ accepted answers to find the one answer I earned a bounty for.  I know I can look through my rep audit and find it, but I'd still be interested to see bounties that others have won when I look at their profiles.  It would be cool if the answer list showed awarded bounties on answers in the list, something like this:

[image]

Comment: You know that for yourself, you can easily hunt down bounty winnings using your reputation audit and searching for vote code "9", aye? ♪

Comment: @Grace: shh! yes, I knew that.  I don't think I do have any awarded bounties, though - I mostly want to nosey at other people's :-)

Comment: This is difficult to implement for now since multiple answers in the same question get combined into one item in that list (which is a separate discussion). I like this idea, though. I think putting the +500 on the right side after the question title would make more sense so it doesn't take up a whole column of real estate.

Comment: @Jon: that's something I hadn't thought about although, just like it would show combined score for multiple answers, it could show combined bounties.  I had thought about having the bounty award on the right, either way works for me.

Comment: @Grace: turns out I did get a bounty, quite a while ago though so I'm not surprised I forgot about it.  Shouldn't I have gotten an Altruist badge for that?

Comment: You get Altruist for awarding the bounty, not winning it.

Comment: @Grace: ah, the wording is a little confusing - thanks.

Comment: Bounty tab is now in place with [earned filter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e?tab=bounties&sort=earned) :)

Answer (score 2):

This has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) 6-8 years ago:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140753/andy-e?tab=bounties&sort=earned

[image]

To see your own ones (faster than auditing your reputation), just follow this link:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bounties&sort=earned