# Query bounties set by specific user

Tags: support, bounties, data-explorer

Is there a way to query all bounties ever set by a specific user?

If that is not possible, is there a way to query my own bounties?

Comment: In case somebody stumbles upon this post, I will just mention that it is now possible to create a SEDE query which list bounties started by some user. (Moreover, all offered bounties are also shown in the user's profile.) Since I do not want to repeat exactly the same thing here, I will just add a link to my recent answer on [math.meta.se]: [Number of bounties offered by an user](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34735).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If that is not possible, is there a way to query my own bounties?

You can find all bounties awarded to you and offered by you at [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).  Bounties awarded to you are on a line that begins  `9`   , bounties offered by you are on a line that begins  `8`    (spaces are useful when using your browser's Find feature).  The post ID related to the bounty is listed with them.

I'd still like to see something like [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57657/display-bounty-scores-in-user-profile-answers-list) implemented, but expanded to apply to questions too.

Comment: Very nice, didn't think of that! This works for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

The SEDE, data dump, and API do not disclose who started the bounty (all voters except for favoriters are hidden), so you cannot use these methods.

However, as the data is publicly available by viewing the revision history, you could, in theory, screen scrape every question's revision history to see who cast the bounty. You could perhaps limit the number of questions you would have to check by (either manually or automatically) querying the reputation tab for abnormally large rep loss in a user's profile, but you will have to screen out -100 flag penalties, large amount of downvotes, and perhaps other ways to lose a great mass of reputation.

Comment: I have no idea why the user ids and bounty amounts are stripped from this vote type...